# colorbox: how to disable next and previous button

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I am developing a website and I have used color box to show my image galleries, when click over each images color box will be appear. what i am asking for how can i disable or remove next and previous button from color box window? and also disable go to next image function from colorbox when we click over image.?

i had tried following changes: `preloading: true,` to `preloading: false,`  but it's not working for me

Comment: just dont put them in the same group?

Comment: its dynamic generated photo gallery, not static. so we can't set different group name for each thumbnails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have find out the solutions, `$(".group1").colorbox({rel:'group1'});` change to `$(".group1").colorbox({});`

it will be disable next and previous buttons also disable image link to next one

Answer (score 3):

In case someone still need it.

Set `rel: 'nofollow'` to disable grouping.

Answer (score 0):

In your colorbox settings set loop to false

http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox check the loop feature on this page.

Comment: i had set loop: false, but now still appear next button and also working next image link.... i just want disable next and previous buttons

Comment: "loop:false" will not help, it only disables looping - i.e. jumping from last to first on the "next" link.