# Colorbox - Removing Next & Prev Buttons

Tags: jquery, button, colorbox

I'm trying to remove the next and prev buttons from the cboxOverlay. All I want to be displayed is the close button (cboxClose) and the styling to display the photos.

I've tried applying the suggestions mentioned in [this earlier thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17649716/colorbox-how-to-disable-next-and-previous-button) all without success. I've got Colorbox 1.6.4 installed, btw, and that thread is from 2013.

Disabling grouping via the setting `rel: 'nofollow'` removes the close button (cboxClose) and the styling to display the photos as well as the next and prev buttons - not what I'm after. Plus the line of code `$(".group1").colorbox({rel:'group1'});` no longer appears to exist.

I can see that the inline attribute `style="inline-block"` is added to the cboxNext and cboxPrev button ids and unchecking that attribute using the browser developer tools does actually remove the buttons as required. However, when I attempt to remove the style attributes for the next and prev buttons by adding the following code to the end of the jquery-colorbox.js file:

```
if document.getElementById('next' || 'prev') {
    .removeAttr("style")
};
```

or:

```
if document.getElementsByTagName('button') && document.getElementById('next' || 'prev') {
    .removeAttr("style")
};
```

likewise that again removes the close button (cboxClose) and the styling to display the photos as well as the next and prev buttons.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution is to simply comment out the following 4 lines in the colorbox.css file:

```
    /*
    #cboxPrevious{position:absolute; ... }
    #cboxPrevious:after{ ... }
    #cboxNext{position:absolute; ... }
    #cboxNext:after{ ... }
     */
```

Doing so retains the close button (cboxClose) and the styling to display the photos as required while removing the next and prev buttons.